# Gradle: Delete files from directory, based on Filelist

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm currently trying to migrate my old ant system to gradle. I'm pretty new to gradle and still learning, so maybe this is something trivial I just overlooked.

I got a file, called *delete.list* which contains a list of files I want to delete.

This is my code so far:

```
task deleteLib(type:DeleteFiles) {    
    deleteList = file("${buildDir}/delete.list")
}



 class DeleteFiles extends DefaultTask {

    @SkipWhenEmpty
    @InputFile
    File deleteList

    DeleteFiles()
    {
        description = 'Deletes Libs from Integris zip'
    }

    @TaskAction
    void delete(){
        def lines = deleteList.readLines()
        lines.each {
            delete fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}", include: "${it}")
        }
    }
}
```

delete.list:

```
lib/java/activation.jar
lib/java/pdfbox*.jar
lib/java/fontbox*.jar
lib/java/xmpbox*.jar
lib/java/jempbox*.jar
lib/java/iText*.jar
lib/java/itext*.jar
lib/java/jakarta-poi.jar
lib/java/commons-net*.jar
lib/java/jfreechart*.jar
lib/java/jcommon*.jar
lib/java/dom4j*.jar
lib/java/xmlbeans*.jar
lib/java/jaxen*.jar
lib/java/avalon-framework*.jar
lib/java/batik-all*.jar
```

After googling a bit I found this solution, as my _delete.list **may** not exist during building phase.

My current problem is that gradle seems to have a problem with the `fileTree` method:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deleteLib'.
> Could not find method fileTree() for arguments [{dir=C:\entwicklung\Testumgebung\testProjectGradle\build, include=lib/java/activation.jar}] on task ':deleteLib' of type DeleteFiles.
```

Have somebody an idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since both methods are defined on [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) and groovy looks for the method defined in task you need to explicitly invoke the methods on `project` instance:

```
project.with {
   delete fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}", include: "${it}")
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how this works (guess I'm back to reading gradle doc), but it solved my issues.
Thanks alot.